# How to make format validation function for input text with Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I have form like this

```
<p>Masukan Posisi Baru</p>
<input type="text" id="nposisi"/></br>
<button id="ok">OK</button>
```

on "OK" click function i must validate that text input not empty and accordance with my format.

my format input text:

1. combine font and  numeral
2. have 3-5 font
3. must capital font
4. coma and another punctuation mark not allowed except dot

ex: A2.8

for empty validation just simple

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ok").click(function(){
       var nposisi = $("#nposisi").val();
       if(nposisi==""){
          alert("Masukan dulu posisi baru");
          exit();
       }
    });
});
```

but my problem i have no idea in format validation? any idea for this. Thank's before

Comment: What does `exit()` do?

Comment: to exit "if" function

Comment: Well, there is no `exit` function in JavaScript! JavaScript programmers use `return [false]`.

Comment: you could use the regular

Comment: @Laughing can you tel to me with an example

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression.

```
r = /^[\.A-Z0-9]{3,5}$/;

var nposisi = $("#nposisi").val();
if (nposisi.match(r)) {
    alert("matches!");
} else {
    alert("no match :(");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method to achieve this:

```
if (/^[A-Z\.\d]{3,5}$/g.test(nposisi)) { ... }
```